# what is service metadata and why it's necessary to publish?

Tags: wcf, metadata

There is ABC (addres, binding, contract) = endpoint. I thought this information is enough to communicate with clients and vice versa. But what is metadata and mex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The metadata that the mex endpoint exposes describes the service, the various operations, parameters the opertions require and the return types. In other words, the metadata exposes the contract. With this information the client can create a proxy to interact with the service. Clients use the mex endpoint to access the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Metadata inculdes the following:

1. For clients to create the proxy classes they need to know about the service contract, what operation contracts are available in the service contract, what parameters they take in, what are their data types, what data they will return etc.
2. Without these information clients will not be able create proxy classes.
   Therefore we need to specify the service behaviours.